SASPy: How dtype parameter within sd2df_DISK() function works
I have started working with an EL proccess that transfers data from SAS to Azure using SASPy.
Regarding one specific table, I have found out that the transference of some string fields is forced via dtype within sd2df_DISK(). This works for these strings fields but interferes in the transference of some other date fields, which are turned also into strings -don't know why-.
I'd like to include these date fields in the dtype dictionary to assure they remain as dates, but I can't figure out how to depict the data type: 'date', 'datetime' or 'datetime64[ns]' don't seem to work.
The dtype dictionary currently looks like this (it comes from a .yml file):
TABLE_NAME:  {'str_field_1': 'str', ..., 'str_field_n': 'str'}

So I guess I should modify it this way:
TABLE_NAME:  {'date_field_1': 'correct_date_type', ..., 'str_field_1': 'str', ..., 'str_field_n': 'str'}

Thanks in advance.
Edit
Regarding the comment by Stu Sztukowski, I get this:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 144 entries, 0 to 143
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   DATE    144 non-null    datetime64[ns]
 1   AIR     144 non-null    float64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1)
memory usage: 2.4 KB


Can you try this code and see if it returns a date as expected? It could be that pandas is misreading the date fromat. df = sas.sd2df_DISK(table='air', libref='sashelp')  df.info()

I have edited the original message with the output.

I'm wondering if your date formats are not being interpreted correctly by sd2df. It is using a csv as an intermediary.

So DATE in SASHELP.AIR has DATE values, number of days.  But perhaps Python dataframes do not have a separate data type for dates?  Also that variable is using the MONYY format in SAS, which will display dates as three letter month and 2 digit years.  Perhaps that is also confusing the transfer method?

Pandas DFs seem to have just datatime64[ns] objets to deal with all kind of dates. Moreover, it seems SAS doesn't even have proper dates but just numeric fields that pretend to be dates,

1/2: In base SAS there are two data types: numeric and character. Dates and datetimes are a numeric data type whose format is displayed as a date or datetime. The format of that data item determines how it is displayed to the user, and subsequently interpreted by other software. e.g. I can format the number 0 as DDMMYYD10. and it will display as 01-01-1960. Dates in SAS are the number of days since Jan 1st 1960/number of seconds since Jan 1st 1960, while datetime64[ns] in pandas is the number of nanoseconds since January 1, 1970, at 00:00:00 UTC. Try formatting the date as DDMMYYD10.

2/2: sd2df() uses CSV as an intermediary to convert it to a dataframe, which means if there's a date format pandas doesn't understand, it will probably interpret the value as a string. Without seeing an example of your data I can't make a determination if that is the problem and provide a solution.
